# How to implement "exponential backoff" in this simple mutex implementation?

Tags: c, performance

My mutex implementation simply retries on CAS failure (pseudo code):

```
while(!compare_and_swap(&mutex, 0, 1));
```

But it wastes too many CPU cycles.

I learned that "exponential backoff" improves overall performance. How to implement the backoff delay in C?

- Is there a precise timer API (to implement backoff delay)?
- Does OS offer any facility to implement backoff?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Exponential backoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) is a simple algorithm that decreases the rate of attempts multiplicatively in case of repeated failure. Yes, in case that many threads constantly access a shared variable, waiting a little bit before retrying the CAS can often improve overall performance.

The simplest idea that comes to mind to implement this principle is using exponentially growing sleeps. For instance:

```
#include <unistd.h>

// ...

useconds_t delay = 100000; // Delay in usec

while (!compare_and_swap(&mutex, 0, 1))
{
    usleep(delay);
    if (delay < MAX_DELAY)
    {
        delay *= 2;
    }
}
```

Note that it's a good idea to cap the delay to prevent sleeping for "eternity". Choose a reasonable value for `MAX_DELAY` to your liking.

Comment: And reset the delay to the starting value after a successful connection.

Comment: @mpez0 Of course. But I'd rather reinitialize the delay right before I'm starting another CAS procedure.